# SSID won't take hold on ESP8826 Server

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

In advance... sorry this question is so long.  The essence of my question is to understand Client/Server communication between two ESP8266's.  The IDE at the moment is Arduino, but I prefer working in Atmel Studio 7.  I'm not a pro, I'm a hobby guy.

The code in [Faster communication between two ESP8266 in client-server setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031974/faster-communication-between-two-esp8266-in-client-server-setup) enables a Server-ESP8266 to send data to a Client-ESP8266.  In using this example, the Client doesn't seem to connect because either, I believe, the Client can't see the Server SSID, or the Server SSID isn't being created.

To look for networks, I modified the Client code to scan and display active networks.  The Client scan results doesn't show the new SSID I try to create in the Server code.  What does show in the scan result is an old SSID (called MyESPAP shown below) from a Server/Client program I was running days ago on the same set of chips.  Even 'disconnect'ing doesn't eliminate the old SSID.  The result of this is that the Client never connects and hangs in the "while...WL_CONNECTED" loop and just prints "......" to the monitor and that looks like:

```
Nearby networks found  :4
List of surrounding Network SSIDsâ€¦:
MyESPAP
CellSpot_2.4GHz_0858*
DIRECT-ABWorkCentre 3215
NETGEAR43

Connecting..................... and on and on and on.... forever
```

Other research/experimentation:  Unplugging the Server and running the Client program alone should show the absence of the new or old SSID in the scan result.  But, oddly, in Serial Monitor the Client program generates repeated error code of:

```
Fatal exception (0): 
epc1=0x40100003, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000
```

At first the Serial Monitor result was all gibberish until I changed the baud rate to 74880 - must be some default rate.  The difference between the two responses shown above tell me that the Client is sensing the Server since the behavior is ... different.  Again, I don't know why.

I've been hung here for days.  Ultimately I would like to put the Server on a tennis racket with an accelerometer and put the Client with a SD card on the sidelines to record the G-forces on the racket.  Separating the two devices allows me to isolate the Client/SD card from the forces.  But not until I get connected...  Any ideas friends?

Server Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() 
  {
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP("ESP123", "lol12345");//Fixed - Edited per Dan Davis comment below.
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  //Serial.flush();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Server IP is: ");
  Serial.println(IP);
  }

void loop() 
  {
  char ID, R, G, B, anim_ID;
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  int data_outgoing[5] = {10, 128, 128, 123, 123};
  int mapFun[5];
  Serial.print("Sent data: ");
  Serial.print(ESP.getChipId());
  Serial.println();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    mapFun[i] =data_outgoing[i];
    //mapFun[i] = map(mapFun[i], 0, 255, 0, 128); 
    client.print(mapFun[i]);
    Serial.print(mapFun[i]);
    }

  delay(10);
  }
```

Client Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>       //crl   If this is the Client, why not include wificlient.h?

const char* ssid = "ESP123";
const char* password = "lol12345";//Fixed - Edited per Dan Davis comment 
const char* host = "192.168.4.1";
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup(){
  int count = 0;
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.println();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  delay(10);
  WiFi.disconnect();      //disconnect any previous connections
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("Nearby networks found  :");   //scan for number of nearby networks & print SSIDs
  Serial.println(WiFi.scanNetworks());
  delay(500);

  Serial.println("List of surrounding Network SSIDs…:");
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID(i));
    }
  Serial.println();

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);       //connect to preferred SSID
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    count++;
    }

  Serial.println();       // print SSID name,local IP allotted ,MAC address & signal strength  
  Serial.println();

  Serial.print("Connected to SSID          : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  Serial.print("IP address allotted to ESP : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  Serial.print("MAC Address of ESP         : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());

  Serial.print("Signal strength is         : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("Time for connection(s): ");
  Serial.print(count);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
  {
  WiFiClient client;

  if((client.connect(host, 80)))
    {
    //  Serial.println("Connected");
    //  Serial.print(host);
    //  Serial.println();
    }

  String data;
  data = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  //Serial.println(data);

 for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
    {
    Serial.write(data[i]);
    Serial.print(data[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: easy: you need 8+ chars in your AP password, otherwise it fails silently. I've wasted a lot of time figuring this out, hope i can spare you some of it...

Comment: That did it.  You nailed it.  The new SSID is now being recognized by the network.  Now I can modify the code to suit my needs.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you have an answer, publish it as an answer. Don't leave it in comment. Albert