# ESP8266 TCP reception speed limit

Tags: webserver, webclient, esp8266

I have a server/AccessPoint ESP8266 transmitting experimental 14-byte data to a receiving client/station ESP8266.  My programming IDE and Serial Monitor is Arduino. The transmitted data is being generated at 100 data per second visible in Serial Monitor, and that is controlled by a 10ms delay.  However, the received data is converted into strings and reported less frequently than 2 times a second.  So I'm missing over 98 percent of the transmitted data.  What can I do to speed-up the data reception?  I suspect there are limits of the buffer.  In my research, I have read that there is an acknowledgement response that is time consuming and that can be overridden.  But much of this is abstracted through libraries, and I haven't been able to uncover it yet.

Ultimately I would like to replace the experimental data with accelerometer output.  An SD card is to be added to the receiver to capture/record the data.  The accelerometer is in a high shock environment that would probably destroy the SD card; thus the need to separate the receiver from the transmitter.  I've tested the accelerometer and know it can deliver 10 strings/second containing up to 9 character bytes, plus a \n\r.  So it appears the transmitter can handle that but the receiver cannot.

My questions are, what are the limits of the buffer management of the receiver, is there a acknowledge element, and if so can i defeat it?  What else can I do to get higher data reception speeds?

Here is the salient code for the transmitter/server:

```
void loop() 
  {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  int data_outgoing[5] = {10, 128, 128, 123, 123};
  int mapFun[5];
  Serial.print("Sent data: ");
  Serial.print(millis());
  Serial.println();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    mapFun[i] =data_outgoing[i];
    client.print(mapFun[i]);
    Serial.print(mapFun[i]);
    }
    client.print('\n');
  delay(10);
```

Here is the salient code for the receiver/client:

```
void loop()
  {
    if(client.connect(host, 80));
    {
      if(client.available());
      {             
           String c = client.readStringUntil('\n');  //client.read();     
           Serial.print(c); Serial.print("   "); Serial.println(millis());
      }
    }
      client.stop();
  }
```

The foundation of this work was based off of [this blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031974/faster-communication-between-two-esp8266-in-client-server-setup). For other readers there are great tips/tricks in that discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a few things that may help others and save a bunch of time.  If the below is not correct, please step in.  The below is what I have gathered by reading multiple sources, some of which are probably correct.  Don't know about the rest.

TCP transmissions involve an acknowledge procedure that introduces some overhead burden for each packet transmitted.  To optimize speed and accuracy transmitted data is often placed into suitably sized packets to gain some economy of scale for the acknowledge return overhead.  On the ESP8266 each Client.print transmission will wrap-up the data into one packet, no matter how small, and transmit.  Small packets are costly for both the transmitting ESP and the receiving ESP.  What solved my problem was clustering many data elements into one Client.print statement, plus the '\n\' character used to parse lines in the receiving ESP and delimit the received clusters.  The multiple data elements can then be managed either by the received ESP, or post-processed, which I have been doing in a spreadsheet to evaluate performance.

There is a 1460 byte limit for the packet sizes in TCP (maybe Arduino/ESP specific.)  I found that by 'clustering' 12 three character values, plus 12 control characters (combination of tabs and commas) I ended up with 48 bytes per transmission.  While far short of the 1460 limit, this was far better than my first sequence of: transmit 3 characters, wait for ack, transmit 'n', wait for ack, repeat on and on.  Even just combining the 'n' with the 3 character would have been a 100% improvement, but I did that multiplied by 12.  The result of all of this was a much improved reception speed - so much that I needed to slow down the transmitter.  When I hook up the accelerometer I don't want to go any faster than it's ability to generate x,y,z coordinates which I think is about 10 sets per second.  This also resulted in a higher rate of transmission success - nearly perfect except for occasional gaps.

Speaking of which, after every couple of thousand data elements (occasionally as many as 10K) the receiver would stall out for 7 seconds each time.  I'm working on that one, but I'm suspecting that the devices are reaching a temperature limit (both ESP's get very warm to the touch).  Maybe I should transmit larger packets, less frequently...  But the 7 second delay each time has me thinking it may be some other abstracted detail that the Arduino IDE hides from me.

Another potential source of a solution I have read about is to use client.stream or server.stream.  I dabbled a little bit in that but soon gave up.  I have read that data transmissions of 2.5 Mbps are possible. This experiment is working for me at up to (48B * 8b/B)/0.015mS, or 25.6 Kbps, so much higher speeds are probably possible.    Thought I'd share.

The receiver code is not changed from above.  The transmitter(server) code loop is:

```
void loop() //Works - crl 3/7/18
  {
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  Serial.print("Sent data: ");
  Serial.print(millis());
  Serial.println();
  client.print(String(data_outgoing)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+1)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+2)+'\t'
             + String(data_outgoing+3)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+4)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+5)+'\t'
             + String(data_outgoing+6)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+7)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+8)+'\t'
             + String(data_outgoing+9)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+10)+","
             + String(data_outgoing+11)
             + '\n');
  Serial.print(data_outgoing);
  data_outgoing += 1;
  delay(340);   //
  }
```